# how to display multiple array variables in one HTML tabel?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter, in which I have a controller Studentcontroller and a model StudentModel.
I am fetching data from procedures and have 4 to 5 array variables each is storing different data according to the procedures.
Now, these variables are basically data for every column in HTML table. Now I am having a problem actually I don't know how to use foreach loop in such way that I can show every variable data in table column.

I am sharing controller, model, HTML table view. Please help me out.
Controller -:

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Students extends CI_Controller {
function __construct(){
     parent:: __construct();
     $this->load->model('StudentsModel');

 }

/*******************************************************/
/************* Function for login process **************/
/*******************************************************/
public function index()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('SchoolLoggein') == TRUE){
        $result['class_total_strn'] =      $this->StudentsModel->class_total_strn();
        $result['school_house_list'] = $this->StudentsModel->school_house_list();
        // getting school house strength individual
        $result['class_house_strn'] = $this->StudentsModel->class_house_strn();

        $result['school_gender_list'] = $this->StudentsModel->school_gender_list();
        $result['class_gender_strn'] = $this->StudentsModel->class_gender_strn(); 
        $result['school_section_list'] = $this->StudentsModel->school_section_list();
        $result['class_tptavailstrength'] = $this->StudentsModel->class_tptavailstrength();
        $result['class_classtptNA'] = $this->StudentsModel->class_classtptNA();
        // echo '<pre>';print_r($result['class_gender_strn']);exit;
        $this->load->view('student',$result);
    } 
    // end if userloggedin check
    else {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
}
?>
```

Model -:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');


class StudentsModel extends CI_Model {


    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /****************************************************************/
    /***************** Module for student reports *******************/
    /****************************************************************/

    // Calling procedure for class total strength
    function class_total_strn(){
        $classtotstrength = $this->db->query("CALL classtotstrength('".$_SESSION['session']."','".$_SESSION['msid']."','".$_SESSION['myDate']."','".$_SESSION['courseId']."')");
        $class_strength = $classtotstrength->result_array();
        $classtotstrength->next_result(); 
        $classtotstrength->free_result();

        if(!empty($class_strength)){
            return $class_strength;
        } else {
            return '0';
        }
    }

    // Calling procedure for school house list
    function school_house_list(){
        $schoolhouselist = $this->db->query("CALL schoolhouselist('".$_SESSION['msid']."')");
        $all_schoolhouse = $schoolhouselist->result_array();
        $schoolhouselist->next_result(); 
        $schoolhouselist->free_result();

        if(!empty($all_schoolhouse)){
            return $all_schoolhouse;
        } else {
            return '0';
        }
    }

    //Calling procedure for class house strength individual
    function class_house_strn(){

        $schoolhouselist = $this->db->query("CALL schoolhouselist('".$_SESSION['msid']."')");
        $all_schoolhouse = $schoolhouselist->result_array();
        $schoolhouselist->next_result(); 
        $schoolhouselist->free_result();

        foreach($all_schoolhouse as $school_house){
            $classhousestrength = $this->db->query("CALL classhousestrength('".$_SESSION['session']."','".$_SESSION['myDate']."','".$_SESSION['msid']."','".$_SESSION['courseId']."','".$school_house['id']."')");
            $house_strength[] = $classhousestrength->result_array();
            $classhousestrength->next_result(); 
            $classhousestrength->free_result();
        }

        if(!empty($house_strength)){
            return $house_strength;
        } else {
            return '0';
        }
    }

    // Calling procedure for school gender list
    function school_gender_list(){
        $schoolgenderlist = $this->db->query("CALL schoolgenderlist('".$_SESSION['msid']."')");
        $gender = $schoolgenderlist->result_array();
        $schoolgenderlist->next_result(); 
        $schoolgenderlist->free_result();

        if(!empty($gender)){
            return $gender;
        } else {
            return '0';
        }
    }

    // Calling procedure for gender strength
    function class_gender_strn(){
        $schoolgenderlist = $this->db->query("CALL schoolgenderlist('".$_SESSION['msid']."')");
        $gender_list = $schoolgenderlist->result_array();
        $schoolgenderlist->next_result(); 
        $schoolgenderlist->free_result();
        foreach($gender_list as $gender){
            if(!empty($gender['gender'])){
                $classgenderstrength = $this->db->query("CALL classgenderstrength('".$_SESSION['session']."','".$_SESSION['msid']."','".$_SESSION['myDate']."','".$_SESSION['courseId']."','".$gender['gender']."')");
                $total_gender_stern[] = $classgenderstrength->result_array();
                $classgenderstrength->next_result(); 
                $classgenderstrength->free_result();
            }
        }

        if(!empty($total_gender_stern)){

            $result = [];
            foreach ($total_gender_stern as $value) {
                $result = array_merge($result, $value);
            }
            return $result;
        } else {
            return '0';
        }
    }

    // Calling procedure for school gender list
    function school_section_list(){
        $schoolsectionlist = $this->db->query("CALL schoolsectionlist('".$_SESSION['msid']."','".$_SESSION['myDate']."')");
        $school_selection_list = $schoolsectionlist->result_array();
        $schoolsectionlist->next_result(); 
        $schoolsectionlist->free_result();

        if(!empty($school_selection_list)){
        return $school_selection_list;
        } else {
            return '0';
        }
    }

    // Function for fetch count of total transport
    function class_tptavailstrength(){ 
        // Calling procedure for get count all employees
        $tottransport = $this->db->query("CALL classstptavailstrength('".$_SESSION['session']."','".$_SESSION['msid']."','".$_SESSION['myDate']."','".$_SESSION['courseId']."')");
        $final = $tottransport->result_array();
        $tottransport->next_result(); 
        $tottransport->free_result();

        if(!empty($final)){
            return $final;
        } else {
            return '0';
        }
    }

    // Function for fetch count of total transport
    function class_classtptNA(){ 
        // Calling procedure for get count all employees
        $tottransport = $this->db->query("CALL classtptNA('".$_SESSION['session']."','".$_SESSION['msid']."','".$_SESSION['myDate']."','".$_SESSION['courseId']."')");
        $final = $tottransport->result_array();
        $tottransport->next_result(); 
        $tottransport->free_result();

        if(!empty($final)){
            return $final;
        } else {
            return '0';
        }
    }
}
```

HTML Table -:

```html
<div class="page email-page col-md-12">
 <div class="row">
  <table class="table mb-0 thbg">
   <thead>
    <tr class="Top">
     <td rowspan="2" align="center">Class</td>
     <td rowspan="2" align="center">Total</td>
     <td colspan="2" align="center">Gender</td>
     <td colspan="4" align="center">House</td>
     <td colspan="2" align="center">Section</td>
     <td colspan="4" align="center">Category</td>
     <td colspan="2" align="center">Transport</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Top">
      <td class="simple" align="center">Boy</td>
      <td class="simple" align="center">Girl</td>
     <td title="Green" align="center"> G </td>
     <td title="White" align="center"> W </td>
     <td title="Blue" align="center"> B </td>
     <td title="Safforn" align="center"> S </td>
     <td title="section" align="center"> S1 </td>
     <td title="section" align="center"> S2 </td>
     <td title="General" align="center"> Gen </td>
     <td title="S.C." align="center"> S.C. </td>
     <td title="S.T." align="center"> S.T. </td>
     <td title="O.B.C." align="center"> O.B.C. </td>
     <td class="simple" align="center">AVL</td>
     <td class="simple" align="center">NA</td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr>

     <td align="center">
      <a title="my class" class="style24" href="#">KG</a>
     </td>

     <td title="my total" align="center">
      <a href="#">25</a>
     </td>
     <td title="Boys" align="center">
      <a href="#">54</a>                                            
     </td>
     <td title="Girls" align="center">
      <a href="#">17</a>                                            
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a title="Green" href="#">22</a> 
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a title="White" href="#">8</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">                                                
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">                                                
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a title="A" href="#">30</a>  
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>                                            

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">27</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">3</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">21</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">9</a>
     </td>

    </tr>
    
    <tr>

     <td align="center">
      <a title="my class" class="style24" href="#">KG</a>
     </td>

     <td title="my total" align="center">
      <a href="#">25</a>
     </td>
     <td title="Boys" align="center">
      <a href="#">54</a>                                            
     </td>
     <td title="Girls" align="center">
      <a href="#">17</a>                                            
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a title="Green" href="#">22</a> 
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a title="White" href="#">8</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">                                                
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">                                                
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a title="A" href="#">30</a>  
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>                                            

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">27</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">3</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">21</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">9</a>
     </td>

    </tr>
    
    <tr>

     <td align="center">
      <a title="my class" class="style24" href="#">KG</a>
     </td>

     <td title="my total" align="center">
      <a href="#">25</a>
     </td>
     <td title="Boys" align="center">
      <a href="#">54</a>                                            
     </td>
     <td title="Girls" align="center">
      <a href="#">17</a>                                            
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a title="Green" href="#">22</a> 
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a title="White" href="#">8</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">                                                
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">                                                
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a title="A" href="#">30</a>  
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>                                            

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">27</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">3</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">0</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">21</a>
     </td>

     <td align="center">
      <a href="#">9</a>
     </td>

    </tr>
    
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: you mean the actual `foreach` in the template? https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html you can consult the manual for that, there are examples

Comment: You need to present data for one row at least. From PHP.

Comment: @Kevin i know basic foreach. But here I am facing different issue I am not able to extract value from every variable accordingly.  I think I do not know how can i define my exact problem.